# unable to to post data from dynamic text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my application I have dynamic text box.I am unable to send data by post to another page.

```
<form method="post" action="questionmadddb.php"> 
<?php
$num=$_POST['num']; //this is a number which come from another php page as a dropdown number(2-10)
for ($i=1; $i <=$num ; $i++) { 
echo "<tr>
<td><label>OPTION " . $i . "</label></td>
<td><input class='form-control' name='txtoptname$i'></td>
<td></td><td></td>

</tr>";
}
?>
 <td colspan=6><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" >ADD QUESTION</button></td>
</form>
```

this is a form, I want to send this data by post method.

this is retrieve data code

```
$option=$_POST['txtoptname'];
echo $option;
```

i want to echo that all value. If two or three text box present by dynamic and all field are fill up then in next page all data will echo.
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: because you don't have text box with name `txtoptname` your textboxes names are `txtoptname1`, `txtoptname2`,  `txtoptname3` and so on..

Comment: "_this is a form_" Those are some form fields, you're missing the `<form>` tag

Comment: yes...that is my concept

Comment: form tag is present in my code.this is only part of the dynamic text box. other form data send perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.Since you want all value so better to create `name` as an array.***

```
<form method="post" action="questionmadddb.php"> 
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['num'])){
        $num=$_POST['num'];
        for ($i=1; $i <=$num ; $i++) { 
            echo "<tr>
            <td><label>OPTION " . $i . "</label></td>
            <td><input class='form-control' name='txtoptname[]'></td>
            <td></td><td></td>
            </tr>"; // name is an array now
        }
    }
    ?>
    <td colspan=6><button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" >ADD QUESTION</button></td>

</form>
```

***2.Change code of `questionmadddb.php` like below:-***

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['txtoptname'])){
  $option=$_POST['txtoptname'];
  print_r($option);
  foreach($option as $opt){
    echo $opt."<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes..it work correctly..just one thing i need to know about this..can you tell me how to insert those array value in mysql database instead of echo?

Comment: You need to read some threads of insertion code. You need to use a foreach and run query inside foreach and save data. You can use multiple values at-a-time concept too to save data in a single-query without foreach. read latestes examples for it using `mysqli_*` or `PDO` library (latest library of php for db management)

Comment: please give  me some example ...i am using mysqli

Comment: 3 thing in my db table. 1.id(auto),2.question(this is a id which comes from other table),3.option(this is the array value).. I want to insert different option name with same question id.. can you tell me how i do that?